# Google Calendar with Sql Server DB

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to associate a sql server database with a google calendar i.e. have the calendar read from and update the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look through the [google developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) for their calendar. It appears that you would have to have some type of application to create specific xml from your database that can be set with a 'post' method to google and retrived with a 'get' method for dislaying.

Just looking at the sidebar here on Stackoverflow, it seems that a lot of people have asked about the google calendar application, and you maybe able to find a lot more information by searching the related questions.

Good luck with your project, and hope this helps some.