# Google Calendar integration with Sql Server DB

Tags: .net, sql-server, forms, database-design, google-calendar-api

*You might notice that this question has a similar title to one asked two years ago.
[Google Calendar with Sql Server DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000242/google-calendar-with-sql-server-db?rq=1)
However, although the answer to that question said that there were many similar questions on SO, I have thus far failed to find them, and I am unsure if such answers would even still be relevant as the Google Calendar API has since been replaced.*

I was initially planning to pursue the **development of an online appointment system** by integrating Google docs (spreadsheet) and Google Calendar. I know that it *is* possible to integrate both systems, albeit with considerable tweaking. Both the Google Docs form and the Google Calendar would represent parts of the User Interface (through iframes on a website). Users could book through the form, and see what appointments were available by looking at the calendar.

However, the spec has been changed such that I must now use a Relational Database Management System. As such, Google Docs no longer seems such a good bet (or any bet at all). Consequently, this question specifically concerns  the notion of integrating SQL Server with Google Calendar. The reason for using Google Calendar is the fact that it would provide such a stable, good looking interface for users, and also provide opportunities for easy collaboration and data sharing.

So the design would look something like this: a Form (preferably designed through Microsoft Access), would send data to a Single Table (possibly with a key formed by combining the date and time parameters - no two appointments can be at the same time). A calendar (hopefully Google Calendar) will take info from the date, time, name and contact details fields of the form, and update accordingly. Users would then be able to see what times are available, and the owner of the website would be able to share this appointments calendar with employees.

The table used for this could also be connected to other tables, but no other table would have any direct bearing on the calendar.

So what do people think? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 4):

I am unsure if this is correct but after a hell of a lot of web trawling this link has become the best candidate to date. Putting it here for self-reference as much as anything else.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f3124d4-2f19-4d8e-bddb-272431a3b33d